# Covariance function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I want to find covariance function for $W_t^2$, $W_t$ - Brownian motion. Can you help me with it? I don't know where to start.

Comment: Start with the definition of covariance, at least.

Comment: @Nap D. Lover: thank you, what would I do without you. Any constructive thoughts?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356784/covariance-of-squares-of-brownian-motion you can try to follow the answers here too.